# Confused with telerik event handlers

Tags: c#, event-handling, telerik

I'm not sure if this is right for getting a value of a multi combo box

when user selects something i need to get it's first column value and pass it to my DB

i'm trying to get a value from the *telerik Multicombo box* and idon't know wich event handler to use?

here's my code

```
        private void radMultiColumnComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radMultiColumnComboBox3.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            radMultiColumnComboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            var item = radMultiColumnComboBox3.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.Rows[0];
            radGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PLS select a row", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean that the event handler in your code example isn't invoked when the index is changed?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the value of the first column when the user selects a row in the Telerik's MultiColumnComboBox:

```
void radMultiColumnComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = radMultiColumnComboBox1.EditorControl.Rows[radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

You can find the documentation of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/multicolumncombobox-selectedindexchanged.html).